# Recursive CTE in hive

Tags: java, hive, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression, recursive-cte

I have a recursive CTE written in SQL server which i need to migrate to HIVE.
As hive does not support recursion in CTE, i am stuck here. i am advised to write a java UDF for this but i am not expert in java. If anyone could help here, i would be great.

Code(SQL server) :

```
            WITH CTE_CATEGORY_TREE AS 
            (
                                            SELECT CT.seq
                                                            , CT.[name]
                                                            , CT.pseq
                                                            , convert(varchar(255), CT.seq) AS [sort]
                                                            , convert(nvarchar(255), CT.[name]) AS [depth_fullname]
                                            FROM [dbo].[table1] AS CT WITH(NOLOCK)
                                            WHERE CT.pseq = 0 
                            UNION ALL 
                                            SELECT PC.seq
                                            , PC.[name]
                                            , PC.pseq
                                            , convert(varchar(255), convert(nvarchar,CT2.sort) + N' > ' + convert(varchar(255), PC.seq)) AS [sort]
                                            , convert(nvarchar(255), convert(nvarchar,CT2.depth_fullname) + N' > ' + convert(nvarchar(255), PC.[name])) AS [depth_fullname] 
                                            FROM [dbo].[table1] AS PC WITH(NOLOCK)
                                            JOIN CTE_CATEGORY_TREE AS CT2 ON PC.pseq = CT2.seq
            )

            SELECT          seq
                            , [name]
                            , pseq
                            , sort
                            , depth_fullname 
            FROM CTE_CATEGORY_TREE
```

Comment: How did you go about this?

Comment: hive is not mature enough yet to deal with this. wrote java code.